# Looking for software that can index local html files and search the results, displaying the results with a browser-like interface

Tags: windows

I downloaded the cppreference documentation as well as others that I use often and I'm loving using offline documentation (I mean it is all html, just on your computer not on a web site), except for one thing.. I can't search it. Does anyone know of any program that can index local files and perform web-like searches on them and browse the web page results?

the **key** here is that I'm not looking for file search software, or software that can extract parts of documents. Rather I would like something that finds the spot in an html document and then you can continue browsing that HTML document.

Comment: Maybe you can look if you get such documentations as a complete PDF in which you can search?

Comment: @jmizv that won't really help because i need to be able to browse the file. It is a programming reference after all.. whenever people use this site they click on links on the page many times.

Comment: But if the PDF is done well it supports hyperlinks in it so that you can go to another page within the document. But I see.

Comment: I think you might be confusing a book teaching the language with a reference. The reference has to document and link to everything. That would be a mammoth pdf, and every page has a lot of links.. see for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string